# NPM not running postinstall

Tags: node.js, npm

I've installed a custom package called @company/cdk-library.

It has package.json scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "build": "tsc",
    "prepublishOnly": "npx tsc --skipLibCheck",
    "installLambdas": "(cd constructs/account/mylambda/code/ && npm i)",
    "postinstall": "npm run installLambdas"
  },
```

When I install this package into my project using: `npm i @mycompany/cdk-library@5.0.0 --foreground-script`

I don't get any indication that it's ran the `postinstall` script. If I check the directory, there's no dependencies there either.

Output from install:

```
➜  cdk git:(cdk-update) ✗ npm i @mycompany/cdk-library@5.0.0 --foreground-scripts
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated sane@4.1.0: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added

added 504 packages, and audited 523 packages in 16s

25 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

1 critical severity vulnerability

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

However, if I do it manually by running `cd node_modules/@mycompany/cdk-library && npm run postinstall`

It runs it fine, output:

```
cdk-library git:(cdk-update) ✗ npm run postinstall                                                               

> @mycompany/cdk-library@5.0.0 postinstall
> npm run installLambdas

npm WARN deprecated axios@0.19.2: Critical security vulnerability fixed in v0.21.1. For more information, see https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/3410

added 82 packages, and audited 83 packages in 1s

...
```

Does anyone know why my postinstall isn't running when I install the package?

Comment: What npm Version are you using? Just tested postintall with npm `7.17.0` and it runs correctly.

Comment: Running NPM 8.15.1

Comment: I downgraded to NPM 7.24.2 and same issue. I then downgraded to NPM 6.14.17 and it runs the postinstall fine! Why in later versions does it not run I wonder?

Comment: Hmm interesting I just upgraded to 8.15.1 and it still works for me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this has been here for a while, but I just ran into it myself and what I finally worked out, is that "postinstall" will only be callled with you actually using "npm install ..."

If you happen to use the shortcut "npm i ..."  it won't be called.  You would need to add a script entry for "posti" in order to have it also work with the shortcut.

Hope this helps others.

Comment: thank you! but so weird! :o